# Changes image based on time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery

good evening all. I'am a beginner programmer, I need your help in changing the image based on the time of day. for example:

- 00-11am = image A
- 12pm-18pm = image B
- 19pm-23pm = image C

Can anyone help me? I know that I need to use JS but I don't know how to implement it properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
let currentTime = new Date().getHours();
let img = document.getElementById('myImage')

if (currentTime >= 0 && currentTime <= 11) {
  img.src = 'image 1 link'
} else if (currentTime >= 12 && currentTime <= 18) {
  img.src = 'image 2 link'
} else if (currentTime >= 19 && currentTime <= 23) {
  img.src = 'image 3 link'
}
```

change myImage to whatever your images ID is, and change the image sources to the links to your image files.